# How to Load Angular 2+ Routes in a New BrowserWindow (Electron)?

Tags: angular, electron

So I have a finished Angular 5 app that I want to covert into an Electron app. I've gotten everything to work in the app as it did in its Web App form except for one thing. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to load Routes into a new BrowserWindow. Here is what I am working with and what I have tried so far:

I load mainWindow with this:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
```

I successfully navigate to Contact via routerLink in mainWindow and get this result:

```
console.log(mainWindow.webContents.getURL()); = file:///C:/Me/Project/dist/contact
```

Now instead of navigating to Contact inside of mainWindow, I want the Contact page opened inside of secondWindow via mainWindow:

index.html:

```
<base href="./">
```

app.routes.ts:

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'contact', data: { sectionTitle: 'Contact' },
    loadChildren: 'contact/contact.module#ContactModule'
}]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

main.js:

```
secondWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    frame: false,
    minWidth: 1024,
    minHeight: 768,
    show: false
  });

secondWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + 'dist/contact');
secondWindow.show();
```

This results in this error message:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Me/Project/dist/contact
```

What I have tried with no luck (tried hash routes as well w/ useHash: true):

```
secondWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/dist/contact');
secondWindow.loadURL('file:' + __dirname + '/dist/contact');
secondWindow.loadURL('file:' + __dirname + 'dist/contact');
secondWindow.loadURL('file:' + __dirname + 'dist/index.html#/contact');
```

Any ideas? It's the only thing holding up the release of this Electron app.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without seeing your code and Angular setup it's tricky to know why its not working. You should however be using the node.js `path` and `url` modules to build your url.

At a guess, I would say that you need to load your base html file and the hash should be the route you're wanting to load:

```
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

window.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
  protocol: 'file:',
  slashes: true,
  hash: '/contact'
}));
```

Which would give something like:

```
file:///full-path/to-your/app-root/index.html#/contact"
```

That means your last example was the closest but manually building the url yourself means that it was not valid:

> `secondWindow.loadURL('file:' + __dirname + 'dist/index.html#/contact');`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the hash property. I tried to give as much code as I could since it's company code I've been working on. For this example I was just trying to directly load a route on startup, instead of traversing the app to the routing location. I am going to give this a shot as soon as I get to work and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried this out in various ways without any luck. It's basically redirecting me back to my homepage, or throwing an error saying that I am not allowed to load a local resource. What other info would you need?

Comment: Ok so I logged what url.format was creating and this is the url that I am getting: `file:///C:\full-path\app-root\dist\index.html#/contact`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: The url in our Electron app (in dev mode) looks like: `file:///C:\Users\tim\Documents\Repos\AppName\index.html`

Comment: Yes that is what I am getting for my contact route. Whenever I try to open the contact route in a new BrowserWindow, it redirects me back to my homepage.

Comment: Are you using webpack? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5107 , https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4867

Comment: Yes I am. I was originally using Angular/CLI, but ejected the webpack config so I can include `target": "electron-renderer"` to avoid using ngx-electron.

Comment: The url for your second window should be the same as for the first window but with the addition of the hash

Comment: Ya I can't get this to work. We can chat about it if that helps.

Comment: Turned out you were right. I spent a few hours adding and removing different packages and modules, and it turned out that an import of ngx/charts was what was preventing the entire project from using manual routing.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1so did this work? I am trying to achieve something similar (basically loading a component within onto a second window).

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 - were you able to resolve it ? i have similar problem to load an angular route in child window.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the currently accepted answer, I also needed to turn on `useHash` in `AppRoutingModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: I didn't have any routes and I was getting this error. This fixed my issue though. Thanks.