# Opening new Window - Electron

Tags: electron

I'm currently trying to implement a new Window on my Electron App.
So I want to include a button, and when you click on this Button, a new Window should be opened.
I didn't find anything in the Electron documentation, maybe one of you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Load Angular 2+ Routes in a New BrowserWindow (Electron)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308385/how-to-load-angular-2-routes-in-a-new-browserwindow-electron)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('<your_button_id>');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   createBrowserWindow();
});

function createBrowserWindow() {
   const remote = require('electron').remote;
   const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
   const win = new BrowserWindow({
     height: 600,
     width: 800
   });

   win.loadURL('<url>');
}
```

Comment: Does this work with Electron? Do youknow where to implement this? I dont think it's possible to implement this in the .ts class.

Comment: Without a doubt it works with electron. Include it in the script tag of your html. Please read the electron docs and go through the basics.

Comment: It does not work anymore: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: not working...const remote = require('electron').remote; makes a problem

Comment: You have to set the flag `enableRemoteModule` to true while creating the main browser Window if you want access to the remote object. You can read more about it here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote

Comment: not working, it is better to use `loadFile` by the way

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer that has been taken as correct is outdated.
I have managed to do it with the [ipc module](https://www.electronjs.org/es/docs/latest/api/ipc-main) and with the solution given by Nishkal.
Please, read the ipc module, I'm new to electron and not very experienced with programming. I'm sure you can come with better solutions.
Code I added in order for it to work:

**my main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

//ipc
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  createWindow();
})

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
        
    });

    win.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
})
```

**my preload.js**

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
        ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
            console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
          })
        //button and its event listener
        const b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
        b1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a window from the renderer:

```js
window.open("https://github.com", "_blank", "top=500,left=200,frame=false,nodeIntegration=no");
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/window-open