# Electron + Angular Application + Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, electron

I have the angular + electron app with the below structure

[image]

Routes in the Angular App looks like this, with the lazy load for the wrapper modules

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'lib', loadChildren: () => import('./wrapper/wrapper.module').then(m => m.WrapperModule)},
  {path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./wrapper/homewrapper.module').then(m => m.HomewrapperModule)},
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
];
```

The code works perfectly well when launched as a Angular application in browser localhost:4200. However, it doesn't work if it launched as Electron app. The HomeComponent, which is the default route comes up perfectly fine in Electron BrowserWindow. However the following URLs doesn't work with lib URL

**Without hash**

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Technical/ElectronJS/Demo2/electron-demo/dist/electron-demo/index.html/lib

**With hash**

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html' core.js:4061 file:///D:\Technical\ElectronJS\Demo2\electron-demo\dist\electron-demo\index.html#\lib

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution. If someone is looking for the answer, the solution mentioned in this post solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010347/4951812